# How to create a Style for a border in MAUI?

Tags: maui

In my `MAUI` project, I have a `Border` with those properties

```xml
<Border x:Name="border" Style="{StaticResource borderFlashCard}">
    <Border.Stroke>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Gray100}"
                          Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource Gray500}"
                          Offset="1.0" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Border.Stroke>

    <VerticalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                         VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label x:Name="label1" Text="One side" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Border>
```

I want to move those properties in the `Style.xml` like that

```xml
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderFlashCard">
    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black}" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint" 
            Value="0,1" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.GradientStop.Color" 
            Value="DarkGray" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.GradientStop.Offset" 
            Value="0.1" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.GradientStop.Color" 
            Value="LightGray" />
    <Setter Property="Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.GradientStop.Offset" 
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 13" />
    <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
    <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="90" />
    <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, it is not working and the error is this one:

> XFC0040   Cannot convert value "Stroke.LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint" to "Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableProperty".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LinearGradientBrush` is a class instance and not a property, which itself requires `GradientStop` **instances** while style setters can only be used to set **property values**. What you can do, however, is set a `LinearGradientBrush` instance to the `Stroke` property that contains several `GradientStop` instances:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderFlashCard">
  <Setter Property="Stroke">
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
      <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0.1" />
      <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="StrokeShape" Value="RoundRectangle 13" />
  <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
  <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="90" />
  <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="100" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following in Styles.xaml:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="borderFlashCard">
        
    <!--<Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Black"/>-->
    <Setter Property="Stroke">
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Offset="0.1" Color="DarkGray">
            </GradientStop>
            <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="LightGray">
            </GradientStop>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I can't use `Value` as a parameter of `Property="Stroke"`, I get the error `XLS0501 The property 'Value' is set more than once.`

Comment: yes we cannot set the value of same property more than once like the error says. I made this mistake sorry for that. Since we have using LinearGradientBrush for the value of Stroke property, then we cannot set the ```Value="Black"``` again. Just comment it out.

Comment: Interestingly, although XLS0501 error appears, the project can also be compiled. And the previous value will be overwritten.